# Change the Bluetooth inquiry scan time

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

According to the method [`BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery%28%29), the discovery process usually involves an inquiry scan of about 12 seconds. Is there any thing to reduce the inquiry time scan (lower than 12 seconds)?

This is my `MainActivity`:

```
package com.example.bluetoothsignal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText statusText;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        statusText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.statusText);

        statusText.setText("");
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(
                BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        IntentFilter localIntentFilter1 = new IntentFilter(
                "android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND");
        registerReceiver(this.mReceiver, localIntentFilter1);
        IntentFilter localIntentFilter2 = new IntentFilter(
                "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED");
        registerReceiver(this.mReceiver, localIntentFilter2);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        this.mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent) {
            String action = paramIntent.getAction();
            if ("android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND".equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice localBluetoothDevice = (BluetoothDevice) paramIntent
                        .getParcelableExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE");
                int s = paramIntent.getIntExtra(
                        "android.bluetooth.device.extra.RSSI", -32768);
                short s2 = paramIntent.getShortExtra(
                        "android.bluetooth.device.extra.RSSI", Short.MIN_VALUE);
                int s1 = paramIntent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,
                        Integer.MIN_VALUE);

                String state = localBluetoothDevice.getAddress() + "\n"
                        + localBluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n" + s + "\n" + s1
                        + "\n" + s2;
                statusText.setText(statusText.getText().toString() + state);
            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = paramIntent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a
                // ListView
                statusText.setText(statusText.getText().toString()
                        + device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            } else if (("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED"
                    .equals(action))) {
                if (MainActivity.this.mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    MainActivity.this.mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
                statusText.setText("");
                MainActivity.this.mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I do not think you have control over this, because the Bluetooth discovery protocol takes time to scan for nearby devices, which is part of the Bluetooth stack.

Comment: maybe is there any option that when the bluetooth discover the first device, it can stop to scan? or to start manipulate the first discovered device while the bluetooth continue to scan? thanks

Comment: If you want to connect to a specific device you can store its mac address and connect directly without scanning

Comment: thanks alot, if i have the MAC address of the device, how can i connect directly and find his bluetooth signal strength?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to a device where you don't know the complete adress, you'll have to do a complete discovery with `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` and search the received addresses for the ones you want to.

If you know the complete address of the device you want to connect to you can directly connect to this device with `BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);`

So by directly using `.getRemoteDevice(address);` you can save the the for scanning devices. Instead directly connect...

Example:

```
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice("00:1C:4D:02:A6:55");

sock = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("8e1f0cf7-508f-4875-b62c-fbb67fd34812"));
```

Then `sock.connect();` etc.. hope you got it

Answer (score 1):

You can call startDiscovery when it stops. In your boardcast receiver:

```
if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action))
{
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
```